# Easy way to convert ForEach table into Datatable Jquery table?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement the sorting functionality of Datatables by clicking on the headers to sort.
I'm currently loading my data using a ForEach like so. Is there an easy way to implement the sorting functionality in my scripts? Thank you

```
    <tbody>
     @foreach (var fieldValidator in field.FieldValidators)
   {
<tr>
    <td>
        @fieldValidator.Id
    </td>
    <td>
        @fieldValidator.ValidatorType
    </td>
    <td>
        @fieldValidator.ErrorMessage
    </td>
    <td>
        @fieldValidator.Param1
    </td>
    <td>
        @fieldValidator.Param2
    </td>
    <td>
        @fieldValidator.Param3
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditFieldValidator", new { fieldValidatorId = fieldValidator.Id, dynamicFieldId = field.Id, dynamicFormId = Model.DynamicForm.Id, vaccineTypeStatusId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary mb-h" })
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mb-h" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-field-validator-@fieldValidator.Id">Delete</a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete-field-validator-@fieldValidator.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>You are about to permanently delete this field validator.</p>
                        <p><b>This action can NOT be undone.</b></p>
                        <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFieldValidator", new { fieldValidatorId = fieldValidator.Id, vaccineTypeStatusId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
 }
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Why not use [datatables.net](https://datatables.net)? If you want to do the sorting in the backend, make it an ajax call to a Controller with a querystring for the sort column that returns the sorted table as html.

Comment: I am using Datatables.net. This is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to follow the guide in https://datatables.net/.

It has no problem if you used forEach. Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />


<div class="container">
    <div class=" row">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Serial Number</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.Id
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.SerialNumber
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Age
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ender91: Well played, my friend :))